# MySQL - JOIN producing "extra" results?

Tags: php, mysql

It would be rather difficult to explain this issue without showing you what I've got, so we'll start with that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scpv6.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZFQR.png]

**Query:**

```
SELECT goodies.title FROM `goodies` LEFT JOIN `goody_images`
ON goodies.id=goody_images.goodie_id
```

**Raw Result:**

candy
candy
hats

**The issue:**

It produces an extra result per each joined value. Because two of the entires in **goody_images** have the a *goodie_id* of *1*, it prints the corresponding *title* from **goodies** twice, hence why we see the result ***candy*** twice. I instead need it to only give my the *title* once, regardless of the number of matching JOIN results.

Is this possible, or am I better off running two separate queries?

In context of PHP, I'm trying to get two values:

-One with the title,
-And and an array with the matching images.

The programming for all of that is already complete are perfectly operational - The issue simply lies in getting the results properly.

+*The above query was abbreviated for simplicity*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct goodies.title 
FROM `goodies` 
LEFT JOIN `goody_images` ON goodies.id=goody_images.goodie_id
```

or `group by`

```
SELECT goodies.title 
FROM `goodies` 
LEFT JOIN `goody_images` ON goodies.id=goody_images.goodie_id
GROUP BY goodies.title
```

Comment: Accepted! - Perfectly simple solution! May I ask, though, what the advantages to each given solution might be?

Comment: If you only need unqiue values you can use whichever you like. But if your query needs other column values to, for instance the number of images for every goody then you need to group.

Answer (score 1):

It is not showing extra record it showing candy two time because goodie_id 1 has two images but if you want to select title only then you can use

```
SELECT goodies.title FROM `goodies` LEFT JOIN `goody_images`
ON goodies.id=goody_images.goodie_id group by goodies.title
```